# How to add numerous objects into an array

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using the following code to load many images into an array, but want to know how to do it more efficiently. For example, how could I efficiently load 100 images into an array?

```
hopAnimation=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-1.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-2.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-3.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-4.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-5.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-6.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-7.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-8.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-9.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-10.png"],
.
.
.
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-100.png"],
              nil
              ];
```

Is there a way to use a for-loop to do this efficiently?

Comment: What makes you think that the way you are doing is not efficient enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop, sure. You might want to put all the image names into a [plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2). Then you can create the array of names:

```
NSArray * imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/names.plist"];
```

and loop through it to create the array of images:

```
NSMutableArray * images = [NSMutableArray array];
for( NSString * imageName in imageNames ){
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
}
```

Or, if your image files are really named consistently like that, you can loop on an integer and put that into the file name string:

```
NSMutableArray * images = [NSMutableArray array]; 
for( int i = 1; i <= numImageFiles; i++ ){
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame-%d.png", i]]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your naming convention is consistent like that, you can use a mutable array and add the items in a loop:

```
NSMutableArray *hopAnimation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];

for (int i = 1, i <= 100, i++) {
   [hopAnimation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame-%i.png", i]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people suggested populating your array with a loop. Your stated goal is efficiency and if anything a loop would be less efficient then the way that you are currently loading your array. If you want to clean up your code, then by all means use a loop. But if you are looking for *efficiency*, there is no way to populate your array that is more efficient then the method that you are currently using.

Comment: There's a loop inside of `initWithObjects:`, too, to deal with the the items in the `va_list`.

Answer (score 0):

If using Clang 3.1 (which will probably arrive with Xcode 4.4) or greater, you can use the new array literal syntax:

```
@[
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-1.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-2.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-3.png"],
    /* ... */
]
```

I haven't found any information on whether that's implemented with a loop like with `-initWithObjects:`, or any other performance considerations.

Comment: This is not available in Xcode 4.3, as that compiler doesn't have these features yet. A future release will support them, though.